# Combining two output values (columns) into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine `SCO_NET_VALUE` + `FRONT_END_NET_VALUE` into new a totals table.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Sample output:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVtuk.png)

Query:

```
SELECT 
    storenumber,
    bbbtendertypetext,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber > 91 THEN (financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount) END) AS SCO_NET_VALUE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber < 92 THEN (financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount) END) AS FRONT_END_NET_VALUE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber > 91 THEN (transactionid) END) AS Transaction_Count_SCO,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber < 92 THEN (transactionid) END) AS Transaction_Count_Front_END
FROM   
    [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender]
WHERE  
    transactiondatetime > '2022-09-22 00:00:00.000'
    AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-23 00:03:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    storenumber, bbbtendertypetext
ORDER BY 
    storenumber
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;). All within the question, no images.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `SUM(financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount)`??

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text .

Answer (score 0):

Please, not that
the columns 'SCO_NET_VALUE' and 'FRONT_END_NET_VALUE' may have a 'NULL' values
due

```
case > 91 and case < 92
```

---

so, first of all
you should decide what value be in 'SCO_NET_VALUE' column if value <= 91?
is it 0?
so, modify that portion to be

```
SUM(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber > 91 THEN (financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount) **else 0** END) AS SCO_NET_VALUE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber < 92 THEN (financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount) **else 0** END) AS FRONT_END_NET_VALUE,
```

then you can do outer query to select sum of these two columns
some thing like this:

```
select storenumber,
    bbbtendertypetext,
    SCO_NET_VALUE + FRONT_END_NET_VALUE as Total,
    Transaction_Count_SCO,
    Transaction_Count_Front_END
from
(

SELECT 
    storenumber,
    bbbtendertypetext,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber > 91 THEN (financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount) END) AS SCO_NET_VALUE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber < 92 THEN (financialamounttendered - financialchangeamount) END) AS FRONT_END_NET_VALUE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber > 91 THEN (transactionid) END) AS Transaction_Count_SCO,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TerminalNumber < 92 THEN (transactionid) END) AS Transaction_Count_Front_END
FROM   
    [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender]
WHERE  
    transactiondatetime > '2022-09-22 00:00:00.000'
    AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-23 00:03:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    storenumber, bbbtendertypetext
) inner query

ORDER BY 
    storenumber
```